# PlotChart/LineChart vertical linear gradient on the line series

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, graph

I want to build a LineChart component where the color of the line is indicative on how high the value is. I should be able to do this buy just using a gradient stroke (see below) but for some reason the gradient only goes from left to right and the "angle" property is being ignored. How could i do this?

```
    <mx:PlotChart id="bpChart" width="514" height="144" dataProvider="{measurementsXLC}"   >
    <mx:series>
        <mx:LineSeries id="bpSeries" displayName="Series 1" yField="value" xField="date" showDataEffect="fade" stroke="{lstroke}">
            <mx:lineStroke>
                <mx:LinearGradientStroke angle="270.0" weight="3"  scaleMode="vertical"  >
                    <mx:entries>
                        <mx:GradientEntry color="#ff0000" ratio="0.0"/>
                        <mx:GradientEntry color="#00ff00" ratio="1.0"/>                         
                    </mx:entries>
                </mx:LinearGradientStroke>
            </mx:lineStroke>
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <mx:CircleItemRenderer >

                    </mx:CircleItemRenderer>
                </mx:Component>                 
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:LineSeries>
        <mx:LineSeries id="bpSeries2" displayName="Series 1" yField="value2" xField="date" showDataEffect="fade"  />
    </mx:series>
    <mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:DateTimeAxis id="dateAxis" dataUnits="milliseconds" labelUnits="days" />
    </mx:horizontalAxis>
    <mx:verticalAxis>
        <mx:LinearAxis baseAtZero="false" autoAdjust="true" interval="5" />

    </mx:verticalAxis>
</mx:PlotChart>
```

Answer (score 3):

After encountering the same problem and using James Hay's explanation/example above, I constructed my own LineSegmentRenderer.

Basically I wanted to have a top-to bottom gradient stroke in my lineChart. I too found out that the angle or more accurately the rotation property of the LinearGradientStroke wasn't effective in the LineSegmentRenderer, so I made a copy of ShadowLineRenderer and edited its updateDisplayList method (see code below).

In this updateDisplayList method the LineSeries lineStroke property is set to a LinearGradientStroke so I could use the stroke color entries which are set in the 'calling'/lineChart constructing MXML module (where also the stroke weight is set).

I found that the essential part in creating a top-to bottom gradient is to use a GradientBox in defining the lineGradientStyle. For a top-to-bottom gradient the GradientBox rotation property is set to PI/2 (equivalent to 90 degrees). It is propably possible to derive this rotation property (using a degrees-to-radian conversion) from the stroke rotation property (which can be set in the LineSeries lineStroke property) so you can avoid hard-coding the rotation property in this Renderer but instead make it a adjustable parameter when using this custom renderer.

See code:

```
        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number,
                                                  unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

        var stroke:LinearGradientStroke = getStyle("lineStroke");
        var form:String = getStyle("form");
        var gradientBoxMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
        gradientBoxMatrix.createGradientBox(unscaledWidth,0.9*(unscaledHeight),Math.PI/2,0,-0.05*(unscaledHeight));
        graphics.clear();
        graphics.lineStyle(stroke.weight,0);

        graphics.lineGradientStyle(GradientType.LINEAR,[stroke.entries[0].color,stroke.entries[1].color],[1,1],[0,255],gradientBoxMatrix);

        graphics.moveTo(_lineSegment.items[_lineSegment.start].x,_lineSegment.items[_lineSegment.start].y);
        graphics.lineTo(_lineSegment.items[_lineSegment.end].x,_lineSegment.items[_lineSegment.end].y);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that you would need to create a custom lineSegmentRenderer for the line series chart. The current lineSegmentRenderer is a ShadowLineRenderer.  Without actually solving the entire problem myself, i would create a new class based on ShadowLineRenderer and change the updateDisplayList method to draw the line exactly as you needed it.  Then change the lineSegmentRenderer property of your line series to use this renderer.

If it helps I had to do a  very similar thing but with the AreaRenderer. The area gradient was required to be based on the total chart and not to color the full gradient for any area that was displayed (eg with the regular AreaRenderer, if the area just covers the first 20% of the y axis it still used the full gradient which was an undesirable feature for my project).  Here's the solution to my problem where i created my own AreaRenderer and updated the updateDisplayList method:

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number,
                                                  unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

        var fill:IFill = GraphicsUtilities.fillFromStyle(getStyle("areaFill"));
        var stroke:IStroke = getStyle("areaStroke");
        var form:String = getStyle("form");

        var g:Graphics = graphics;
        g.clear();

        if (!_area)
            return;

        var boundary:Array /* of Object */ = _area.filteredCache;
        var n:int = boundary.length;
        if (n <= 1)
            return;

        var xMin:Number;
        var xMax:Number = xMin = boundary[0].x;
        var yMin:Number;
        var yMax:Number = yMin = boundary[0].y;

        var i:int;
        var v:Object;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            v = boundary[i];

            xMin = Math.min(xMin, v.x);
            yMin = Math.min(yMin, v.y);
            xMax = Math.max(xMax, v.x);
            yMax = Math.max(yMax, v.y);

            if (!isNaN(v.min))
            {
                yMin = Math.min(yMin, v.min);
                yMax = Math.max(yMax, v.min);
            }
        }

        if (fill)
            fill.begin(g, new Rectangle(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight));

        GraphicsUtilities.drawPolyLine(g, boundary, 0, n,
                                        "x", "y", stroke, form);

        g.lineStyle(0,0,0); 

        if(boundary[0].element.minField != null && boundary[0].element.minField != "")
        {
            g.lineTo(boundary[n - 1].x, boundary[n - 1].min);       

            GraphicsUtilities.drawPolyLine(g, boundary, n - 1, -1,
                                            "x", "min", noStroke, form, false);
        }
        else
        {
            g.lineTo(boundary[n - 1].x, _area.renderedBase);        
            g.lineTo(boundary[0].x, _area.renderedBase);
        }

        g.lineStyle(0, 0, 0);
        g.lineTo(boundary[0].x, boundary[0].y);

        g.endFill();
    }
```